# Name a view/action 'View' in ASP.NET MVC without modifing routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

Is it possible to name a view/action 'View' in ASP.NET MVC without creating an extra set of route definitions? I thought of attributes, but couldn't find the right one. 'View' as a function name is not possible, because it would hide the method of the deriven `Controller` class.

Example what I mean with view:

```
public ActionResult HereShouldBeViewInsteadOfThisText()
{
    return View();
}
```

So I can use the url `/home/view/id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ActionName` attribute on action method. like

```
[ActionName("View")]
public ActionResult ViewSomething(string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

this workaround is mentioned in this Phil Haack [post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx/)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your view and action names don't have to match. That's just the conventions-over-configuration approach MVC takes. If you want to use a different view name, you just have to pass it as a string to your return call:

```
public ActionResult MyAwesomeAction()
{
    return View("View");
}
```

However, I will say that conventions are conventions for a reason. It's super simple as a developer jumping into an unfamiliar MVC project to say "This is action `Foo`, so I need to edit view `Foo.cshtml`." Don't give up that ease unless you have a good reason.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that. I want to name the action 'View'. So, where you wrote ``MyAwesomeAction`` should be ``View``. I correct that in my first post.